# How many different colourings are there of the cube using 3 different colours?

Tags: group-theory

A cube is called coloured if each of its faces is coloured by one of 3 given colours. Two colourings are considered to be the same if there is a rotation of the cube carrying one colouring to the other. How would you prove there are exactly 57 different colourings of the cube?

I think the approach is to use Burnsides orbit counting theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your approach is correct, and do you see that you should use a group of order 24? Which one? See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) for the full answer. But first try it yourself!